# Как можно сократить код? Возможно ли вообще?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

```
do
        {
            num2 += 1;
            Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
            Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
            Console.WriteLine("Выстрел: " + num2);
            Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
            Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
            Console.WriteLine("Определение X... Нажмите клавишу...");
            short number = (short)GetNumber(Max, delay);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("X= " + number);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Определение Y... Нажмите клавишу...");
            short number2 = (short)GetNumber(Max, delay);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Y= " + number2);
            Console.ReadLine();
            num += (short)CalcScore(number, number2, laps, step);
            Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
            Console.WriteLine("#######################################");
            Console.WriteLine("Шаг: {0}   Счет: {1}", num2, num);
            Console.WriteLine("######################################");
            Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
            Console.WriteLine("Выйти? (y - Да)");
        }
        while (!(Console.ReadLine() == "y"));
```

Comment: Да возможно, вопрос только - зачем?

Comment: Согласен, смысла вообще нет никакого, но этого требует препод. На этом моменте я вообще не понимаю, как это сделать. @ВладимирКлыков

Comment: ну как вариант(что первое приходит в голову сразу по просмотру текста вопроса) - `\r\n` это перенос строки, не нужно 10 раз подряд вызывать функцию, можно вызвать 1 раз и все строки вывести сразу с переносами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте вспомогательный класс, который и будете дальше использовать. К примеру такой:

```
public static class Format
{
    private static Random _random = new Random();
    public static ConsoleColor GetRandomConsoleColor()
    {
        var consoleColors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor));
        return (ConsoleColor)consoleColors.GetValue(_random.Next(consoleColors.Length));
    }


    public static void Title(string text, string line = "#######################################")
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
    }

    public static void Text(string text, bool isPaused = false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        if (isPaused) Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Ну и далее используйте его:

```
do
{
    num2 += 1;
    Format.Title($"Выстрел: {num2}");
    Format.Text("Определение X... Нажмите клавишу...", true);
    short number = 33;
    Console.WriteLine($"\nX= {number}\n");
    Format.Text("Определение Y... Нажмите клавишу...", true);
    short number2 = 44;
    Console.WriteLine($"\nY= {number2}\n");
    num += 55;
    Format.Title($"Шаг: {num2}   Счет: {num}");
    Console.WriteLine("Выйти? (y - Да)");
}
while (Console.ReadLine() != "y");
```

*Неизвестные мне методы убрал, там смотрите сами...

Это если смотреть именно на сокращение консольных выводов, тут даже не сокращение, а некая группировка повторов в отдельные методы.

Ну а вообще такое стоит делать по принципу ООП, где у вас есть некий объект, он имеет метод Shot со своей логикой, а так получается вы в одном методе делаете все просчеты, это не хорошо...

Comment: ИМХО - код короче не стал, просто теперь он разнесен в разные места =) хотя может быть этого и требуют от автора вопроса =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Зато при дальнейшем вызове скажем заголовка, будет идти не 5 строк, а 1. На таком небольшом кусочке разницы почти нет, да, но при расширение - код будет в разы чище.

Comment: Если сие(что привел автор) и есть вся программа - то использование ООП для нее перебор.. если же это малая часть - то стоит подумать над ООП.

Answer (score 0):

Вы как минимум можете использовать пространство имен  `using static System.Console;` 
   при его использовании Вы можете убрать все "Console" с класса Main